# I have an empty dataframe which I want to fill using another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, is-empty

I have an empty dataframe which is my template

`temp <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=3)) 
colnames(temp) <- c("variable", "group", "bin")`

And another dataframe which has the details of these:

`info <- data.frame(group_abc = c("1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3"), bin_abc = c("0-700", "700-750", "750-800", "800-850", "850-900", "900-950"))`

I want the variable name to be "group_abc", and group to have values of group_abc and bin to have values of bin_abc.

When I was trying to use the values from the dataframe, it gives me an error saying: `Error in`$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, group, value = c("0-699", "700-750",  : 
  replacement has 6 rows, data has 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign (value of) the existing dataframe to the new name but change the column names which can be done in one easy step:

```
 info <- data.frame(group_abc = c("1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3"), bin_abc = c("0-700", "700-750", "750-800", "800-850", "850-900", "900-950"))
 temp <- setNames( info, c("group", "bin"))

> temp
  group     bin
1     1   0-700
2     2 700-750
3     2 750-800
4     3 800-850
5     3 850-900
6     3 900-950
```

If you had wanted only a portion of the existing dataframe to get duplicated, you could have selected either rows or columns or both using "[" on the `info` argument with the setNames call.

Answer (score 0):

You could resolve this by setting up the temp dataframe to have the correct number of rows as well as the correct number of columns when being initialized.

```r
info <- data.frame(group_abc = c("1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3"), bin_abc = c("0-700", "700-750", "750-800", "800-850", "850-900", "900-950"))

temp           <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=3, nrow = nrow(info))) 
colnames(temp) <- c("variable", "group", "bin")

temp$group <- info$group_abc
temp$bin   <- info$bin_abc
```